# Detect which ChartArea is being double-clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, double-click

I have a chart (myChart) and more ChartArea in MyArea that is the ChartAreasCollection. I have to determinate if a double click is made in a certain ChartArea of the collection for select it. With the code written below every ChartArea has the same values for limits (x,y) so the if-condition is always true, even if the click was done on the first area.

Every chartarea can be visible or not so for use this function I have to check with the counter ActiveAreas if are visible more then one.

```
private void chartInForm_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ActiveAreas > 1)
    {
        Point mouse = ((MouseEventArgs)e).Location;

        foreach (ChartArea ca in MyArea)
        {
            if (mouse.X > ca.Position.X &&
                mouse.X < ca.Position.X + ca.Position.Width * myChart.Width / 100 &&
                mouse.Y > ca.Position.Y &&
                mouse.Y < ca.Position.Y + ca.Position.Height * myChart.Height / 100)
            MessageBox.Show(ca.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I take it that you are catching the click event for all charts in the same method, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
private void chartInForm_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(ChartArea ca in chartInForm.ChartAreas)
    {
        if (ChartAreaClientRectangle(chartInForm, ca).Contains(e.Location))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(" You have double-clicked on chartarea " +  ca.Name; 
            break; 
        }
    }
}
```

The key is using `Position.ToRectangleF` when calculating the pixel positions of the CAs; it will bring back the result even when the `ChartArea` is positioned automatically..:

```
RectangleF ChartAreaClientRectangle(Chart chart, ChartArea CA)
{
    RectangleF CAR = CA.Position.ToRectangleF();
    float pw = chart.ClientSize.Width / 100f;
    float ph = chart.ClientSize.Height / 100f;
    return new RectangleF(pw * CAR.X, ph * CAR.Y, pw * CAR.Width, ph * CAR.Height);
}
```

Note that invisible `ChartAreas` by default will not be clicked nor will they take up space and the others will move to their place. But if you set fixed positions this **may** change and you may indeed need to add a check for `ca.Visible` ...