# How can I align the innerPlots?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

I have 2 charts: `chart1` and `chart2`.

I want both charts to have same `innerPlotSize` and `location`.

But `chart1` has a secondary yaxis.

This does NOT work:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AlignWithChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.PlotPosition;
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.Vertical;
```

Comment: You could create a new Postition for the second chartarea from the one of the first chartarea. simply copy the x and Width form one then keep the Y and Height from the other!

Comment: chart2.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition = chart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition; appears to make NO DIFFERENCE. Also, where do I find width of InnerPosition?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I had assumed that the two charts are actually in the same chart control in different chartareas. If they both are set to auto the code indeed makes no difference. you need to get the actual numbers (in percent of the respective container !!) by calling `RectangleF r1 = chart.ChartAreas[0].Position.ToRectangleF();
            RectangleF r2 = chart.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();`

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221672/constrain-aspect-ratio-in-windowsforms-datavisualization-chart/36248343#36248343)  [and here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491231/ms-chart-rectangular-annotation-width-in-percent-and-not-pixel/36497262#36497262) for a discussion! - In your case it would require you to pick the one where the Left value is the larger as the template for left&width..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will align the `InnerPlotPositions` of two `Charts`:

```
    // align the controls:
    yourChart1.Left = yourChart2.Left;
    yourChart1.Size = yourChart2.Size;


    // get the numbers of the current innerplotpositions
    RectangleF ri1 = yourChart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();
    RectangleF ri2 = yourChart2.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition.ToRectangleF();

    if (ri1.Width < ri2.Width)
    {
        yourChart2.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition =
            new ElementPosition(ri1.Left, ri2.Top, ri1.Width, ri2.Height);
    }
    else 
    {
        yourChart1.ChartAreas[0].InnerPlotPosition =
            new ElementPosition(ri2.Left, ri1.Top, ri2.Width, ri1.Height);
    }
```

Before and after:

[image][image]

Comment: That seems quite good -thank you. Only problem now is that when first chart is in Zoom mode, second is miss-aligned by the amount of the yAxis scroll bar. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I believe the scrollbars are part of the chararea, not the innerplotposition. So we'll have to go back one step and calculate the values from both. The ipp ist nested in the chartarea which is nested in the chart client rectangle. - . I'm tied up tonight; I hope I can get it to work tomorrow.

Comment: Actually the IPP are still aligned when zooming in on the (originally) larger of the charts. The solution is simple: You need to re-align them on every zoom just as on every resize! So best call the alignment from the ScaleViewChanged event!

Comment: Thanks for this. After I had got this working - I realised it would be much easier to have 2 chartArea on the same control (I believe you mentioned that in another thread). Then you can use the Align functionality which works perfectly.