# WinForm C#: Chart Overdraw with in panel and auto scroll not helpfull

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have created a window form in this form i have a panel and chart control in chart control i have four chart area and i have resize my chart according to [Constrain aspect ratio in WindowsForms DataVisualization Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221672/constrain-aspect-ratio-in-windowsforms-datavisualization-chart).The problem i have face when chart's draw inside a panel with auto scroll it's overflow without scroll. I need to show full graph with scroll.

Comment: Have you: (1) Anchored the controls to the top and left of the panel and (2) set the panel's `AutoScroll` property to `true`?

Comment: i already use same options and it's producing this result

Comment: You may want to set `panel.AutoScrollMinSize = chart.Size;` - Note that this is a limitation of winform  with anchor=rightand has nothing to do with charts. see [here on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscroll(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Have to tried by giving panel a fix width and height OR AutoSizeMode property of panel ?

Comment: i have used autosizemode with fix panel width and height but not working